# ZonedDateTime to MySql -- Wrong Offset?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, java-time, zoneddatetime

Setup: Spring Boot '2.4.1' application, (hibernate 5.4.25), Java 11

**Question** How do i save a Date (German-Time) with java.time* so that runtime = db

**Problem**:

During Debug:
ZonedDateTime = 2021-05-03 16:11:42.021236

In DB:
Datetime(6)
2021-05-03 14:11:42.021236

```
@Entity
public class User {
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

//getter&setter
```

```
//calling the setter like like: 
user.setCreatedAt(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")))
```

```
//saving via JPARepo...
Repository.save(user);
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

#tried but no effect
hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=CET

#tried but no effect
hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC
```

gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

Comment: What is the data type in MySQL? `timestamp`? `datetime`? As far as I know, MySQL cannot save the time zone from the `ZonedDateTime`, so how would you expect this to work? Also which `ZonedDateTime` would you expect to get back when you retrieve the value again?

Comment: 1) Datetime(6)
2) I don't know if ZoneDateTime is the correct class. I Just want to save a Date like: Year-Month-Day HH:MM:SS:xxxxxx 2021-05-03 16:11:42.021236 according to the German timeline and get it back as saved

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` should work for saving into and retrieving from a `datetime` in MySQL. However neither a Java `LocalDateTime` nor a MySQL `datetime` defines a point in time since they don’t hold time zone or UTC offset. The recommended way is storing into `timestamp` in MySQL and then using Basil Bourque’s answer. A `timestamp` in MySQL is always in UTC (contrary to what you said you wanted).

Comment: thank you for these guiding questions and answers :)

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is "a point in time" and what not ?

Comment: ah, i need to read more carefully... "defines a point in time since they don’t hold time zone or UTC offset"

Comment: But why is TIMESTAMP recommended? since it "only" has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' according to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html . I mean i hope it'll feel like a long time subjectively :D but if the application should run for 20 years...

Comment: If Olivia in Atikokan, Canada, is on a phone call with Franco in Córdoba, Argentina, and they say *now* at the same time, they establish a point in time even though the time is 18:30 in Atikokan and 20:30 in Córdoba. The recommended way to communicate the time is in UTC, where it will be 23:30. What is not: 2021-05-05T20:30 is not a point in time because 20:30 in one time zone can be 25 hours apart from 20:30 in another time zone.

Answer (score 3):

I do not use Spring nor Hibernate, so I cannot help there specifically. And you have omitted crucial details such as the exact data type of your database column, so no specific answer is possible. But I can give you some general pointers.

### Use `OffsetDateTime` with `ZoneOffset.UTC` to communicate moments in JDBC

Regarding `ZonedDateTime`, know that the [JDBC 4.2 spec](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) requires support for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html). Oddly enough, the spec omits to require support for the more commonly used [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) classes. This design choice by the Java team befuddles me, especially with regard to `Instant` which is trivially simple to convert back-and-forth.

➥ Anyways, focus on using `OffsetDateTime` for your JDBC work.

Generally best to do all your business logic, data exchange, data storage, logging, and debugging in UTC. That is, with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, and no time zone. Use a time zone only where required by a business rule or the expectation of the user in presentation.

The basic class for moments as seen in UTC is `Instant`. Generally, this should be the type of your class member fields that track a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

Capture the current moment using [`Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#now()). To record when the "user" object is created:

```
Instant userCreated = Instant.now() ;
```

To record a moment in the database, your column must be of a type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In MySQL 8, that means `TIMESTAMP`, *not* `DATETIME`. See [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

To write our `Instant` object’s value to the database, your JDBC driver may be able to handle the `Instant` object despite being optional in the JDBC spec. If not, or if you want to write more portable code, [convert to `OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset)). Specify the constant of [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) for an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = userCreated.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Pass that object to your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Easily convert back to a simple `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

To adjust to Germany time, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

Understand that MySQL stores all `TIMESTAMP` values in UTC, only UTC. Unfortunately, some middleware and tooling may choose to impose time zone adjustments to the values you retrieve from your database. Using the code above, I believe you will not have that problem.

Comment: so i guess the right question to ask is:

"do i need to save in a zone-specific Date to the DB ?"

 --> "probably not, just go with UTC Standard,  use Instant.now() == point in time (UTC+-0) that i can write to db, but if so, then use OffsetDateTime"

--> Later on, e.g. when frontend asks for it: Convert to ZonedDateTime


Dear sir, thank you very much for your taking your time for that detailed clarification!

Comment: also: if using TIMESTAMP it will automatically save in UTC only. I'll use the helpful source you provided to learn about the different DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types